# Prove $p \in \mathbb{P}$ is a divisor of $(a+b)^{p^n} - (a^{p^n} + b^{p^n})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve the following

> Let $p \in \mathbb{P}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove by induction on $n$: $p$ is a divisor of $(a+b)^{p^n} - (a^{p^n} + b^{p^n})$.

I think the idea is to use the fact that $p \in \mathbb{P}$ is a divisor of $\binom{p}{v}$ for $1 \leq v \leq p-1$.

For $n=1$ I show the following:

I can write $(a+b)^{p} - ( a^{p} + b^{p} )$ as $a^{p} + b^{p} + \sum_{v=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{v} a^{p-v} b^{v} - ( a^{p} + b^{p} )$. This becomes $\sum_{v=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{v} a^{p-v} b^{v}$ and I can apply the idea from above; since $p \in \mathbb{P}$ and $1 \leq v \leq p-1$, $p$ divides all parts with $\binom{p}{v}$.

I presume that for $n$ the formula holds: $p$ is a divisor of $(a+b)^{p^{n}} - ( a^{p^{n}} + b^{p^{n}} )$

Now I want to do the induction step, and that is the part that I am struggling with: $(a+b)^{p^{n+1}} - ( a^{p^{n+1}} + b^{p^{n+1}} )$

I tried to write it out and see if I can continue with that: $(a+b)^{p^{n+1}} - ( a^{p^{n+1}} + b^{p^{n+1}} ) = $
$a^{p^{n+1}} + b^{p^{n+1}} + \sum_{v=1}^{p^{n+1}-1} \binom{p^{n+1}}{v} a^{p^{n+1}-v} b^{v} - ( a^{p^{n+1}} + b^{p^{n+1}} ) =$
$ \sum_{v=1}^{p^{n+1}-1} \binom{p^{n+1}}{v} a^{p^{n+1}-v} b^{v}$

I don't know how to continue with this.

I also tried to use $(a+b)^{p^{n+1}} - ( a^{p^{n+1}} + b^{p^{n+1}} ) =$
$(a+b)^{p^{n}p} - ( a^{p^{n}p} + b^{p^{n}p} )$

I'am stuck at this one too.

Comment: This is a trivial application of Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: I did not get that far yet in the book. I checked. and Fermat's Little Theorem is shown later. I apologize that I did not clarify that. I was not aware. Thank you for the input though.

Answer (score 3):

If $(a+b)^{p^n}\equiv a^{p^n}+b^{p^n}\pmod p$, raising both sides to the $p$'th power, we find
$$
(a+b)^{p^{n+1}}\equiv (a^{p^n}+b^{p^n})^p\equiv a^{p^{n+1}}+b^{p^{n+1}}\pmod p,
$$
where the second congruence is an application of the base case with $a$ replaced by $a^{p^n}$ and $b$ by $b^{p^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b)^{p^{n+1}} - ( a^{p^{n+1}} + b^{p^{n+1}} ) =$$
$$((a+b)^{p^n})^p - ( (a^{p^n})^p + (b^{p^n})^p )=$$
$$\overset{ind.hypoth.}=(kp+ (a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}))^p - ( (a^{p^n})^p + (b^{p^n})^p )=$$
$$\overset{ind.base} =Kp+(a^{p^n} + b^{p^n})^p- ( (a^{p^n})^p + (b^{p^n})^p )=$$ $$\overset{ind.base}=Kp+\kappa p.$$

Comment: Thank you. I believe that is the prove that I was looking for (I'm reading a book and Fermat's Little Theorem was not mentioned yet).